# LEM2 algorithm implementation in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I'm new on StackOverflow and this is my first question.
I have problem with part of LEM2 algorithm. I have something like that:

```
public class Rule {
        String atribute { get; set;}
        String value { get; set;}

        public Rule(){}

        public Rule(String atribute, String value){
            this.atribute = atribute;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

public class RuleObject {
        Rule rule { get; set; }
        List<int> indexList { get; set; }

        public RuleObject(){}

        public RuleObject (Rule rule, List<int> indexList){
            this.rule = rule;
            this.indexList = indexList;
        }
    }

public static void Main (string[] args){
            List<int> G = new List<int> (){ 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
            List<RuleObject> ruleObjectList = new List<RuleObject> ();

            ruleObjectList.Add (new RuleObject (new Rule ("inflation", "decrease"), new List<int> (){1,2,7}));
            ruleObjectList.Add (new RuleObject (new Rule ("inflation", "no_change"), new List<int> (){3,4,5,6,8}));
            ruleObjectList.Add (new RuleObject (new Rule ("budget", "no_change"), new List<int> (){1,5,8}));
            ruleObjectList.Add (new RuleObject (new Rule ("budget", "increase"), new List<int> (){2,3,4,6,7}));
            ruleObjectList.Add (new RuleObject (new Rule ("reserve", "increase"), new List<int> (){1,3,7,8}));
            ruleObjectList.Add (new RuleObject (new Rule ("reserve", "decrease"), new List<int> (){2,4,5}));
        }
```

And i have to do:

1. Select a rule that indexList cover maximum values from G.
2. If a tie occurs, select a rule  with minimum values outside G.
3. If another tie occurs, select first pair.

Example:

1. Inflation-decrease & budget-increase & reserve-decrease covers 3 rules from G.
2. From those 3 rules we choose inflation-decrease & reserve-decrease.
3. In result we select rule inflation-decrease.

Any suggestion how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jdweng said, you should make the properties `public`. Then you can try this code (for me it works as you described):

```
public class Rule
{
    public String atribute { get; set; }
    public String value { get; set; }

    public Rule() { }

    public Rule(String atribute, String value)
    {
        this.atribute = atribute;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class RuleObject
{
    public Rule rule { get; set; }
    public List<int> indexList { get; set; }

    public RuleObject() { }

    public RuleObject(Rule rule, List<int> indexList)
    {
        this.rule = rule;
        this.indexList = indexList;
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> G = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
        List<RuleObject> ruleObjectList = new List<RuleObject>();

        ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("inflation", "decrease"), new List<int>() { 1, 2, 7 }));
        ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("inflation", "no_change"), new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 }));
        ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("budget", "no_change"), new List<int>() { 1, 5, 8 }));
        ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("budget", "increase"), new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }));
        ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("reserve", "increase"), new List<int>() { 1, 3, 7, 8 }));
        ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("reserve", "decrease"), new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5 }));

        // See which rules are included and/or escluded form G.
        // Later we'll take the result based on this.
        var candidates = from r in ruleObjectList
                             select new
                             {
                                 rule = r.rule,
                                 contained = r.indexList.FindAll(num => G.Contains(num)),
                                 excluded = r.indexList.FindAll(num => !G.Contains(num))
                             };

        // Take the ruleObject which has most values inside G and least values outside G.
        var result = candidates.OrderByDescending(c => c.contained.Count) // Order descending by contained rules in G
                               .ThenBy(e => e.excluded.Count) // Then order ascending by excluded rules from G
                               .FirstOrDefault(); // Take the element on top of the list, the result, or return null
                                                  // if there are no results.

        // Print final result.
        Console.WriteLine("Result is " + result?.rule.atribute + "-" + result?.rule.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is awesome. You save my day :)

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you make more of the properties public.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Rule
        {
            public String atribute { get; set; }
            public String value { get; set; }

            public Rule() { }

            public Rule(String atribute, String value)
            {
                this.atribute = atribute;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        public class RuleObject
        {
            public Rule rule { get; set; }
            public List<int> indexList { get; set; }

            public RuleObject() { }

            public RuleObject(Rule rule, List<int> indexList)
            {
                this.rule = rule;
                this.indexList = indexList;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> G = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
            List<RuleObject> ruleObjectList = new List<RuleObject>();

            ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("inflation", "decrease"), new List<int>() { 1, 2, 7 }));
            ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("inflation", "no_change"), new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 }));
            ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("budget", "no_change"), new List<int>() { 1, 5, 8 }));
            ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("budget", "increase"), new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4, 6, 7 }));
            ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("reserve", "increase"), new List<int>() { 1, 3, 7, 8 }));
            ruleObjectList.Add(new RuleObject(new Rule("reserve", "decrease"), new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5 }));

            var results = ruleObjectList.Where(x => x.indexList.Where(y => G.Contains(y)).Count() == 3).ToList();
        }
    }
}
​
```